# How to retrieve Material-UI <TableRow/>'s information based on selection on ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material-UI's `<Table/>` (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table) with `<TableRow/>` with checkboxes set up on a ReactJS project. I am able to select the row by checking off the boxes, but how can I actually get it to log the information selected for that particular row?

I tried but only able to print how to ID of the row selected, rather than the information on that row.

http://www.webpackbin.com/4Jsi-1cn-

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
http://www.webpackbin.com/Ey6da192b

Selected rows are getting by key from array in a state.

Comment: sorry but it is still not logging the information on the row selected? For example, if a row is selected with a checkbox and clicked the button log, want it to log vin, start time, end time, etc. for that particular row selected.

Comment: All informations i printed to console by console.log. All you need to display it as you want.

Comment: Look at this: http://www.webpackbin.com/Ey6da192b
Added bin.log to log info in webpackbin

Comment: Thank you so much but is there a reason why it needs to be clicked twice in order for console log to work? I selected a row and clicked Log once but nothing logs. So I had to click Log button twice every time to get some to log.

Comment: In my browser data is logged after each click.

Comment: Looks like thewebpackbin links are not working.. @marcint339 , can you check this?